# Please recommend a version of Ubuntu or other linux which can run on the 6th generation intel i5 core

Tags: livedvd

Just set up a new desktop with the 6th generation intel i5 core (6500) processor, 16GB RAM, and use the on-chip GPU for display. I tried to run Ubuntu 14.04 TLS 64bit version without installation, but I was only able to see the center aligned "Ubuntu ...." screen with purple background. After that it ended quietly at a completely black screen.

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant, but it might be worth a try: [Early Intel Skylake Linux Users May Run Into A Silly Issue](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=intel-skl-prelim-support)

Comment: Thank you both for providing these valuable information, I 'll read closely and try if I can make some progress this weekend.